# Black areas on mesh, lighting issues. Unreal Engine 4

Tags: 3d, blender, modeling

Very new to unreal engine 4 and 3d modeling in general. I'm having lighting issues. Object looks fine (as seen on the right). The moment I rebuild the lighting however it all goes crazy.
https://i.stack.imgur.com/93KOA.jpg

There's two UV maps assigned to the mesh. 0, and 1.

0 looks like this:  https://i.stack.imgur.com/S4iHA.jpg

1 looks like this: https://i.stack.imgur.com/SIAK6.jpg

Any ideas what's going on here? I've messed with all sorts of parameters but no change, lighting resolution, etc.

*I do get an error on lighting results that says lightmaps are overlapping. I don't see how this is occurring or how to fix it.

Answer (score 0):

Is this model yours?

Have you exported it from for example Blender or 3ds Max?

If so, check if Normals are correctly oriented (they should be outwards from the object)

[This blender tutorial](https://youtu.be/p9Q5c-4AeRA) should be good place to start.